# ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, dataframe

[image] I am running into this problem and for the life of me i've tried everything in my knowledge to fix it but can't get over this issue.

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

house_df = pd.read_csv('house_data_clean.csv', delimiter=',')

grade_cond_df = house_df[['price', 'condition','grade', 'yr_renovated','year_sold']]
grade_cond_df = grade_cond_df.dropna()

x = grade_cond_df[['condition','grade', 'yr_renovated','year_sold']]
y = grade_cond_df[["price"]]

grade_cond_df.head()
grade_cond_df.fillna(0)
XtrainAll, Xtestall, YtrainAll, YtestAll = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

def Mean_Absolute_Error(y_true, y_prediction):
return np.mean(np.abs(y_prediction - y_true)) 

linear_regression = LinearRegression()
linear_regression.fit(XtrainAll, YtrainAll)
y_pred = linear_regression.predict(Xtestall)
print(f"Coefficient of determination: {r2_score(YtestAll, y_pred)}")
print(f"Mean squared error: {mean_squared_error(YtestAll, y_pred)}")

# Plot actual vs predicted values.
plot = sns.scatterplot(x=YtestAll, y=y_pred)
plot.set(title="Actual vs. Predicted Price", xlabel="Actual Value", ylabel="Predicted Value")
```

Comment: Is the CSV file available online so that I can try the code?

Comment: I don't think i can add the files in

Comment: Then you can share using Google Drive! but set the URL as a shareable link...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dFDRPtxUN1cyuZW1JX5hCrxb4hwEJStm?usp=sharing try this

Comment: I sent a permission request!

Comment: I've allowed it